# Resolution change when switching from VGA to HDMI

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, resolution, hdmi, vga

I have an HP Envy dv6 connected by VGA to an LG 27EA63V-P and the HP is getting flaky after updating from Win 8.1 to 10.  Found a nice Acer (Aspire V15 Nitro) that I want to get, but no VGA.  LG has HDMI port and I tested it with the HP.  Works fine, but resolution is low (1366x768) compared to the VGA (1920x1080).  I really don't want to have to buy a new monitor, but I need one in addition to the laptop display.

My question is: Will I be able to get Full HD (1920x1080) with HDMI going from the Acer to my LG?

Thanks.

Comment: It should. The Acer's native res is 1080p, and the GTX 960M supports those resolutions over HDMI, but beware that OEM's may choose to use the component in conjunction with a motherboard or CPU that does not fully support the resolution you want. Find the exact laptop you want (exact model number) and then you can start investigating the parts in it, including the exact CPU, GPU, and motherboard. these components may vary between sub-models in the V15 Nitro line, so its important to find the exact one you intend to purchase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this will work fine.

What is happening at the moment is one of 2 things -  More likely the screen built into your existing laptop is 1366x768, and the display is being mirrored onto your monitor - at a matched resolution.

The alternative is that the EDID (graphics card support reported by computer to the monitor) is being reported at 1366x768 so the monitor is obliging.

HDMI is a much newer standard then VGA, so it can trivially support 1080p.  1080p is also the native (preferred) resolution of your monitor, so it will support it over HDMI.   Any non-ancient PC will support 1080p over HDMI.

Comment: You're right about the laptop resolution.  Interesting that VGA allows the separate monitor to have its own resolution, but HDMI does not (if I understand correctly).

Comment: No, both HDMI and VGA let the monitor have a seperate resolution.  Its more likely to do with a software limitation/configuration setting.